# How to set the tab size of terminal (without "tabs" or "expand")

Tags: shell, awk, tabs

I would like to list some lines of text (stored in a variable or file) starting at i.e. column 3 but doing this without overwriting the columns 1 and 2.

So starting each line with a tab (`\t`) seems to be an appropriate solution. Unfortunately the tab size of my terminal seems to be fixed to 8 (instead of desired 3).

Unfortunately I do not have the command `tabs` because I am working with busybox/ash. Even `expand` does not help because columns 1 and 2 will be overwritten with spaces.

So is there an alternative to tabs? Maybe awk (printf) could be a solution if there is a possibility to set the tab size?

Example:

```
TEXT="line1
line2
line3"
echo "$TEXT" | sed 's/^/\t/'
```

provides

```
         line1
         line2
         line3
```

but I want

```
  line1
  line2
  line3
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you explain where column 1 and  are coming from (why you can't use `| sed 's/^/  /'`) ?

Comment: What do you mean without overwriting columns 1 and 2.  Where are they?  Are you pasting two files together?

Comment: To answer both questions: I would like to show some lines of text in a specific area of the screen (window?). But that should not affect previously printed characters outside this window on the screen. I.e. to list files in a right pan of a commander program without affecting the left pan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than use control sequences which require both row and column to be specified, your terminal probably supports one which moves within the current row.  Referring to [XTerm Control Sequences](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html):

```
CSI Pm `  Character Position Absolute  [column] (default = [row,1])
          (HPA).
```

which would be

```
printf '\033[%d`' $col
```

in the shell.  Also, your text may overwrite previously-written data *after* the text.  You can clear that with another control sequence:

```
CSI ? Ps K
          Erase in Line (DECSEL).
            Ps = 0  -> Selective Erase to Right (default).
            Ps = 1  -> Selective Erase to Left.
            Ps = 2  -> Selective Erase All.
```

`sed` is a little awkward for producing escape characters.  Here is a suggestion in `awk`:

```
TEXT="line1
line2
line3"
echo "$TEXT" | awk '{ printf "\033[3`%s\033[K\n", $0; }'
```

Comment: Ja - that seems work even I don't completely understand your code (especially the one single backtick looks strange). But I tried echoing, folding, heading, tailing and your horizontal moving awk with `echo -n "$TEXT" | fold -s -w $WIDTH | head -n $ENDLINE | tail -n $STARTLINE | awk '{printf "\033['''$COLUMN''''%s\n", $0}'` ... and it worked (had to take here at stackoverflow the egu-tick instead of the back/grave-tick). I have to spent some extra time to understand exactly what I did but thank you so far for saving my weekend.

Comment: The backtic is the final character of the escape sequence.  It happens to be the odd punctuation character in the valid range for *final*.  In testing, I did an `ls -l`, and moved the cursor to home with `tput cup 0 0`, just to see the overwriting.

Comment: I have absolutely no clue what this question was about - good job answering it, whatever it is!

Answer (score 1):

In order to avoid replacing the 1st 2 columns, You'll need to manually move the cursor to the 3rd column and start writing from there. You can't use spaces(using `expand`) since that would overwrite the 1st 2 columns with spaces.(tabs don't overwrite though)

You can use `echo` along with the following escape sequence to position the cursor at line/row `L` and column `C`

```
  \033[<L>;<C>H
     Or
  \e[<L>;<C>H
     Or
  \e[<L>;<C>f
     Or
  \033[<L>;<C>f
```

Here is an example:

Output of the 1st `echo` command:

```
shell@OnePlus2:/ $ clear
shell@OnePlus2:/ $ echo "12\n34\n56"                                           
12
34
56
shell@OnePlus2:/ $
```

Now we'll write another `echo` command that does the following:

1. move cursor to line 2, column 3 and write `line1` after `12`
2. move cursor to line 3, column 3 and write `line2` after `34`
3. move cursor to line 4, column 3 and write `line3` after `56`
4. write out a newline `\n` so that you skip the current prompt(that
   has the `echo` command) and go to next line(this makes cursor come
   at the proper position).

after running the above `echo` command we'll get the following:

```
shell@OnePlus2:/ $ echo "12\n34\n56"                                           
12line1
34line2
56line3
shell@OnePlus2:/ $ echo -e "\e[2;3fline1\033[3;3fline2\e[4;3fline3\n"          
shell@OnePlus2:/ $
```

Note: `12`, `34` and `56` are not overwritten and you have also written out `line1`, `line2` and `line3`.

Note: **the 1st `clear` command is very important** so that you have just the prompt on your terminal, because the line and column values are hardcoded(2,3,4 lines and column 3 for each line). You can however modify my example according to your needs.

If you want to just print from the 3rd column and spaces before that you can use:

```
shell@OnePlus2:/ $ printf "  %s\n" 'line1' 'line2' 'line3'                     
  line1
  line2
  line3
shell@OnePlus2:/ $
```

For more info on escape sequences see: http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x361.html

if you have access to `tput` see: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x405.html

PS: even I'm using a restricted shell, not a full blown `bash` shell:

```
shell@OnePlus2:/ $ echo $SHELL
/system/bin/sh
shell@OnePlus2:/ $
```

As you can see I've connected to my `android` shell's `sh` via `adb`. Since you are using `busybox` which is also available for `android` it should be no problem. However we aren't using any high end shell features, just using `echo` and escape sequences.

PPS: If you can give us more insight on how are your input files organized.. We can just use some other multi file commands such as `paste`, `awk` etc

Edit1: my bad. corrected my answer

Edit2: since you don't have access to `tabs` or `expand` command, you can also use `setterm -regtabs 2` to set tab width/size to 2(it doesn't work in `xterm`'s though giving the error: `setterm: terminal xterm does not support --regtabs`).
However I am able to run it in text mode virtual terminals accessed via `Ctrl+Alt+F[1-6]`.

Comment: Wow - thank you very much for the time you spent to answer my question. ... comment will follow

Comment: No problem :) .. and how are your input files organized? . .why cant you just use `paste` and other multi file commands? .. does my answer solve your problem? ..

Comment: Wow - thank you very much for the time you spent to answer my question. But I have to disagree to your first statement: Echoing a text line starting with a tab (\t) **does not** overwrite the first columns. And that is exactly what it makes so comfortable to echo text within an area of the screen. Actually I would like to show a defined bunch of lines of a help-text within a defined screen-window.

Comment: I use this code to echo and wrap text, insert a tab before each line (sed) and cut specific lines with head an tail: `echo "$TEXT" | fold -s -w $WIDTH | sed 's/^/\t/' | head -n $LASTLINE | tail -n $FIRSTLINE`. Before this code I set the cursor to a specific position on the screen with escape sequences similar to the code you explained very detailled (`echo -n "${CSI}$STARTLINE;"$STARTROW"H"`). Unfortunately the tab before each line is interpreted by my shell with "jump to horizontal position number 9".

Comment: Dealing every printed line with cursor positioning sequences seems to complex and slow now but might be the best workaround for my missing `tabs`command. Sorry for my answer in 4 comments but the number of character per comment is very restricted.

Comment: can you try to use the another command which I've mentioned in Edit 2? .. Is that supported by your shell? .. So is your problem solved using escape sequences?